# probelm in texlive installation

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

I have installed Latex but the errors is as follows...How to resolve this.  I am a first time user of Ubuntu18..please suggest step by step procedure

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
texlive-full is already the newest version (2017.20180305-1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 texlive-full : Depends: texlive-latex-base-doc (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: texlive-music (>= 2017.20170628) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10?

Comment: Try `sudo apt clean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install aptitude   
sudo apt --fix-broken install  
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/
sudo rm texlive-music_2017.20180305-2_all.deb texlive-latex-base-doc_2017.20180305-1_all.deb
sudo aptitude install -f texlive-latex-base-doc texlive-music
```

Comment: Thanks But still the problem persists as follows  "dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-music_2017.20180305-2_all.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/guitar/guitar.pdf' to '/usr/share/doc/texlive-doc/latex/guitar/guitar.pdf.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream

Comment: Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/texlive-music_2017.20180305-2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Thanks to all.  I did as you said and all is well.  No issues now.